# How to manage list of list of rules?

Tags: list-manipulation, simplifying-expressions, string-manipulation, expression-manipulation

Considering we have a list:

```
str =  "{1 -> {a -> aa, b -> bb}, 2 -> {2a -> \"{b -> bb}\"}}"
```

Bringing this to expression gives:

```
In[20]:= ToExpression@str
Out[20]= {1 -> {a -> aa, b -> bb}, 2 -> {2 a -> "{b -> bb}"}}
```

Now I want `"{b -> bb}"` also to be an expression:

```
In[21]:= ToExpression@
  str /. (key_ /; key -> val_) :> (key -> 
    If[StringMatchQ[val, ___ ~~ "->" ~~ ___], ToExpression[val], val])

Out[21]= {1 -> {a -> aa, b -> bb}, 2 -> {2 a -> "{b -> bb}"}}
```

But this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? How to do this correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: I think halirutans solution is about the best you can have for what you asked for, but I have hardly seen cases where transforming between strings and expressions is the best solution to a given problem as that has many potential problems. If you can explain what you try to do in the first place (probably in a new question) you probably will get a much better overall solution than what you are now building on this...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can start by simply creating a function that tests, whether a string is a list of rules or not

```
isTransformable[str_String] := SyntaxQ[str] &&
  MatchQ[MakeExpression[str], HoldComplete[{_Rule ..}]];
isTransformable[___] := False;
```

Note that this function does much more that search for a `"->"` inside a string. First, it tests, whether the string would indeed be a valid expression by using [`SyntaxQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SyntaxQ.html). After this, it makes an expression from the string and really tests whether or not this expression is a list of rules. In all other cases, the function returns `False`.

Now, you can very easily transform your string at once by using

```
str = "{1 -> {a -> aa, b -> bb}, 2 -> {2a -> \"{b -> bb}\"}}";
str //. s_?isTransformable :> ToExpression[s]

(* {1 -> {a -> aa, b -> bb}, 2 -> {2 a -> {b -> bb}}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand your code, especially the `key_/;key->val_` part, but the following code shall do your work:

```
ToExpression@str //. 
 key_String /; StringMatchQ[key, ___ ~~ "->" ~~ ___] 
 :> ToExpression[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MapAt[ToExpression@ToString@# &, #, Position[#, _Rule]] &[ToExpression@#] &@str
(* {1 -> {a -> aa, b -> bb}, 2 -> {2 a -> {b -> bb}}} *)
```